# How do I hook a 3rd party API into Google Actions using Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, voice-recognition

Does anyone know steps to hook a 3rd party API into Google Actions using Dialogflow?

I followed Google's instructions up to creating actions and responses. The app is working in Simulator and in Google Assistant. The baseline is there.

It is not clear how to take a step forward and integrate dynamic data.

**For example, I would like the conversation to be:**

> What's the weather today?
>
> Weather is [x] degrees in New York.

If you could point me to relevant documentation or provide tips, that will be great!

Answer (score 3):

You want to setup [fulfillment](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment) for your Action in Dialogflow.

Some additional information about setting up fulfillment:

- Using the [built-in fulfillment editor](https://dialogflow.com/docs/getting-started/integrate-services-actions-on-google) in Dialogflow
- With the [actions-on-google](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs), [dialogflow-fulfillment](http://.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs), or [multivocal](https://multivocal.info/) libraries.

Comment: Thank you. I now better understand options for setting up fulfillment.

Comment: Great! If either of these answers helped you, accepting one as an answer and/or upvoting them to indicate they helped is always appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

good thing you got started with Actions on Google!

First of all you can have a read of the fulfillment of the documentation [here](http://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment).

Secondly, the GDE Francesco Pontillo created an interesting codelabs with some examples, maybe it can be helpful, link [here](https://github.com/frapontillo/actions-on-google-twitter-raffle/blob/master/tutorial/02-fulfillment.md).

Comment: Thank you. The fulfillment document was helpful. I also found this useful tutorial and was successfully prototyped dynamic weather response. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_oi_tf0AIw

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the relevant answers here, but the problem is you'll not be able to do that with firebase functions as Our Firebase Cloud Function will perform a network request to a 3rd party API. Any network requests outside of Firebase are not possible for free accounts, so testing Action will fail!